# AccessViolationException - is the static method causing this?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection, access-violation

I have created a static method whose purpose is to load a DLL, and using reflection, return an instance of the class contained therein.

To get you in the right mindset, some facts:

1. The exception is occurring in a 3rd party DLL that is being loaded indirectly because of an object instance that belongs to the class being returned (the `ListLabel` public member in `baseClass`).
2. My concern is that this could be my methodology that is causing the failure, and not the fault of the 3rd party assembly.  I would like to try to eliminate that possibility first before I take it to the vendor.

Here is the method in which the exception occurs:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public abstract class baseClass
    {
        public ListLabel LL = new ListLabel();  //this is where the exception actually originates

        public baseClass()
        {
            LL.DrawPage += new DrawPageHandler(LL_DrawPage);
            LL.EnableCallbacks = true;
            LL.AddVarsToFields = true;
            LL.DelayTableHeader = true;
            LL.IncrementalPreview = true;
        }

        public static baseClass GetClassInstance(String DLLName)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DLLName))
                {
                    String fileName = DLLName.EndsWith(".dll") ? DLLName : DLLName + ".dll";
                    Assembly theDLL = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), fileName));
                    foreach (Type t in theDLL.GetTypes())
                    {
                        if (typeof(baseClass).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                            return (baseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(t);  //this line instantiates the baseClass instance, and causes the new LL object to be created, firing the exception
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is ReflectionTypeLoadException)
                {
                    Exception[] exa = ((ReflectionTypeLoadException)ex).LoaderExceptions;
                    for (Int32 i = 0; i < exa.Length; i++)
                        ErrorHandler.WriteError(String.Format("ReflectionTypeLoadException occurred while loading DLL '{0}' (ex #{1}):\n     {2}", DLLName, i, exa[i].ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorHandler.WriteError(String.Format("Error loading DLL: {0}", DLLName));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `baseClass` is the provider of the static method, it is `abstract`, and it is the type being returned by `GetClassInstance()`.

What I get is an *occasional* set of exceptions, with the core of it being an `AccessViolationException`.  The stack trace I receive is as follows:

> at combit.ListLabel18.NativeMethods.LlSetDebug32(Int32 nOnOff)
>   at combit.ListLabel18.LlCore.LlSetDebug(LlDebug onOff)    at
>   combit.ListLabel18.ListLabel.set_Debug(LlDebug value)    at
>   combit.ListLabel18.ListLabel.Init(LlLanguage language, CultureInfo
>   culture, Boolean enableCallbacks, String debugLogFilePath)    at
>   combit.ListLabel18.ListLabel..ctor()    at AllMax.baseReport..ctor()
>   at AllMaxReport.rpt3320DMR..ctor()    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)

This is not consistent by any means, and that is the main reason I am concerned that it's my fault.  Could this have something to do with the combination of:

1. Dynamically load a DLL repeatedly (this tends to happen when looping across many calls to `GetClassInstance()`).
2. Using a `static` method.
3. Putting `reflection` in that `static` method.
4. Creating instances of the same class that provides the `static` method.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, is the behavior any different if you run in release mode?

Comment: @ledbutter I am working under the assumption that it wouldn't, given the obvious calls in the trace.  But I haven't spent a lot of time running in that mode either, so I can't really say.  Being that it's intermittent, it's hard to have any confidence.

Comment: Just stumbled accross this post - best practice would be to have a protection instance of ListLabel in order to avoid the unloading and loading of the DLLs. Simply create a ListLabel object on start up and dispose it when your application is about to close. That should boost performance and get rid of the AccessViolation as well.